# How to change style to a class from a rel attribute CSS

Tags: css, class, rel

i'm working on woocommerce and I'm looking for a way to stytle a class from a rel attribute.

I've manage to change the rel attribute by:

```
a .tagged_as[rel~=tag]{
    color: red !important;
}
```

But it change all the tag rel, I'm looking how to change only one span class (tagged_as) of rel attribute.

(from this html code:)

```
<span class="tagged_as">Tags: <a href="#" rel="tag">Grenache</a>, <a href="#" rel="tag">Syrah</a>.</span>
```

if anybody can highlite me, will be wonderfull, thank you in advance =)

Comment: You try to this .tagged_as a[rel~=tag]{
    color: red ;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now you can try to this**

```
.tagged_as a[rel~=tag]{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the `a` tag the class not the span

```
<span>Tags: <a class="tagged_as" href="#" rel="tag">Grenache</a>, <a href="#" rel="tag">Syrah</a>.</span>
```

Then your CSS should be ...

```
a.tagged_as[rel~=tag]{
 color: red !important;
}
```